# Firebase cloud messaging message id shows but not receiving notifications

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was able to get the message id in return but the notifications are not showing in the android device but it was working fine from the firebase console i can send to topic "nadakko" from firebase console

```
     <?php
 $data = array(
           "message" => "sfsdgdgdfg"
          );
  $final = array(
            "condition" => "'nadakko' in topics",
            "data" => $data
           );

  $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

  $headers = array(
              'Authorization: key=AIzaSyAkjY4wwambC7ryNxr-KEjsx4VgSZuh-UY',
              'Content-Type: application/json'
             );
  // Open connection
  $ch = curl_init();

  // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($final));
  // Execute post
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  if ($result === FALSE) {
      // curl failed
      echo "Faild";
  }
echo $result;
  // Close connection
  curl_close($ch);
  ?>
```

After sending the message i got this error from android monitor the message is received on to the mobile but there is some problem

```
06-07 18:06:16.139 8802-12118/info.***.*** E/MyFirebaseMessagingService: Data Payload: {message=sfsdgdgdfg}
06-07 18:06:16.139 8802-12118/info.**.**** E/MyFirebaseMessagingService: push json: {"message":"sfsdgdgdfg"}
06-07 18:06:16.139 8802-12118/info.**.*** E/MyFirebaseMessagingService: Json Exception: No value for data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
06-07 18:06:16.139 8802-12118/info.**.*** E/MyFirebaseMessagingService: Json Exception: No value for data
```

this is the problem, you need to read the `message` instead of `data`
use so it will be

`String message = json.getString("message");`

Comment: after changin i got this "Json Exception: Value sfsdgdgdfg at message of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

Comment: let me check that

Comment: new  errorJson Exception: Value sfsdgdgdfg at message of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Could you please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
String title = data.getString("title");
String message = data.getString("message");
```